# AlertDialog not appearing on screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a loading dialog using an AlertDialog inside a Retrofit call, however this loading dialog is not showing up at all. I want to show it while the call is downloading and setting up the recyclerView. Right now the dialog is not showing up at all, it sets the recyclerView and everything without showing the dialog. I'm not sure if this matters but this is inside a fragment.

This is the full retrofit call

```
Call<List<Evaluator>> call = apiInterface.getSurveys();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Evaluator>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Evaluator>> call, Response<List<Evaluator>> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            //show error toast
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, null);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        List<Evaluator> masterItem = response.body();

        masterItem.forEach(evaluator -> {
            if (!evaluator.getAnswered()) {
                surveys.add(new Evaluator(evaluator));
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new SurveyAdapter(surveys);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Evaluator>> call, Throwable t) {
        //show error toast
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `dialog.show()` before you call retrofit `call.enqueue`. And inside response or failure dismiss the dialog.

And don't forget to dismiss dialog in both `onResponse` and `onFailure`.

Comment: it loads so fast the screen just goes dark without the dialog, but at least now it's doing something

Comment: yaaa, because your response is immediate.

Comment: yea, for now it is, since the amount of items in the call could change I want to add it just in case, so that the fragment isn't blank while loading. Thanks

Comment: I still have to wait 5 minutes, but I will accept your answer!

Comment: adding dialog before call when necessary is good practice, as we don't know internet speed of user's device, it might low.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212636/discussion-between-nancy-and-nilesh-b).